# Can someone explain how this

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$
x\left\lbrace 4\left[ 1+\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2}\right]\right\rbrace^{-1/2} = \frac{x}{2}\left(1 + \frac{x^2}{2^2}\right)^{-1/2}
$$

This fact was shown in my textbook with no work and I can't figure out how they get from the first equation to the second.

Comment: What is $4^{-1/2}$? You are also missing a parens.

Comment: hahah oh wow. thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$ x ( 4 \cdot (1 + (\frac{x}{2})^2 ))^{-1/2} $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow $$ 
$$ x \cdot 4^{-1/2} \cdot (1 + (\frac{x}{2})^2 )^{-1/2} $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow $$
$$ x \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot (1 + (\frac{x}{2})^2 )^{-1/2} $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow $$
$$ \frac{x}{2} \cdot (1 + (\frac{x^2}{2^2}) )^{-1/2} $$

Basically just power rules